# Inputting the current time into an SQLite database

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I've created a facial recognition program, and I was wondering which would be the best way to input the current time into the sqlite database. I've currently managed to update the attendance of the user, but I'm not quite sure on how to update the time of detection. Below is some of the code I've done for the system.

```
student = getStudent(ID)
connection = sqlite3.connect(r"/Users/...../Documents/...../FaceBase.db")
time = datetime.datetime.now()
command = "UPDATE Class SET Attendance='Present' WHERE ID="+str(ID)
command = "UPDATE Class SET Time = GETDATE()"
cursor = connection.execute(command)
connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

The error that I received was:

```
    cursor = connection.execute(command)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such function: GETDATE
```

Comment: @JonSG I've updated the question and there was an error when running it

Comment: Opps, right. The database function would likely be `datetime('now')`. I *think* that is the default value so you might also be able to simply do `datetime()`  See : https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html for more info. Caution again about parameterized queries and that your second update will update ALL rows as there is no where clause :-)

Comment: @JonSG Thanks for replying! I've managed to fix the issue, and was able to get the current time and date! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to updating the column time is shown below and working with a database function we can use `datatime()`. Below is the command.

```
command = "UPDATE Class SET Attendance='Present', Time = datetime() WHERE ID="+str(ID)
```